# Insert aligned multi-line text in current buffer regardless of position?

Tags: text-editing, insert

I'm creating a function to easily insert `ditaa` boxes while drafting reports in org-mode. I have the meat of the function accomplished, but not sure how to implement it so that boxes can be inserted without losing formatting across new-lines.

Here is the current function:

```
(defun create-ditaa-box (x)
  (interactive "sText: ")
  (let* ((input x)
         (input-list (s-split "\n" input))
         (input-lengths (mapcar 'length input-list))
         (max-len (+ 2 (seq-max input-lengths)))
         (border (concat "+" (make-string max-len ?-) "+"))
         (input-format (mapcar* '(lambda (x y)
                                   (concat "| "
                                           x
                                           (make-string (- (- max-len y) 1) ? )
                                           "|")) input-list input-lengths)))
    (with-current-buffer (buffer-name)
      (insert border)
      (mapc '(lambda (x)
               (newline-and-indent)
               (insert x))
            input-format)
      (newline-and-indent)
      (insert border))))
```

It currently works as expected when my cursor is at the beginning of a line:

```
+--------+
| Hello  |
| World! |
+--------+
```

When creating diagrams I might have a box that needs to be in the center of the buffer. Currently, my function can't handle this:

**Output:**

```
                  <cursor-here>+--------+
| Hello  |
| World! |
+--------+
```

**Expected Output:**

```
                  <cursor-here>+--------+
                               | Hello  |
                               | World! |
                               +--------+
```

Comment: Without looking closely at the question, does library [`boxquote.el`](https://github.com/davep/boxquote.el) help? Or `picture-mode`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the current column and then insert at column `COL` (see `lm-insert-at-column`).

```
(defun create-ditaa-box (x)
  (interactive "sText: ")
  (let* ((input x)
         (col (current-column))
         (input-list (split-string input "\n"))
         (input-lengths (mapcar 'length input-list))
         (max-len (+ 2 (seq-max input-lengths)))
         (border (concat "+" (make-string max-len ?-) "+"))
         (input-format (mapcar* (lambda (x y)
                                  (concat "| "
                                          x
                                          (make-string (- (- max-len y) 1) ? )
                                          "|"))
                                input-list input-lengths)))
    (with-current-buffer (buffer-name)
      (save-excursion
        (insert border)
        (mapc (lambda (x)
                (unless (eobp)
                  (forward-line 1))
                (lm-insert-at-column col x))
              input-format)
        (unless (eobp)
          (forward-line 1))
        (lm-insert-at-column col border)))))
```